# How to update Jest testing framework in create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I already have an application created with [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) package.
I found a bug with the version of Jest which is 15.1.1. But I realized that in version 16 the bug is gone.

How to update Jest?

My problem is in the *package.json* of application there is no Jest package.

Jest is in other folder: *node_modules/react-scripts*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following commands are going to get the job done:

```sh
npm run eject
npm install --save-dev jest@16.0.0
```

But be careful here! The `eject` command irreversibly eliminates the abstraction layer of `create-react-app` exposing all of the dependencies and configuration to you. Though, your app is going to work just like before. You'll just have total control upon it, including the ability to update dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

Create React App updates its dependencies once they are stable enough. This usually means waiting a week or two after the new release.

We don't recommend updating anything by yourself unless this is absolutely critical. If you choose to eject to update something we recommend making it a single commit so that you can revert it later once Create React App uses that version internally.

Comment: Currently Create React App uses Jest 24, which is a year old. Is one week not a thing anymore?

Comment: When can we expect CRA to start using Jest 26?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Wait a week and then do what?