# Jest fails to run when node modules have es6 syntax (create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, jestjs, enzyme

I have a `create-react-app` project and trying to unit test `office-ui-fabric-react` component using `Jest` and `Enzyme`.

The latest version of `office-ui-fabric-react` use `es6` syntax and `jest` is failing to run the test.

```
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import { MessageBar, MessageBarType } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/MessageBar";

describe("<MessageBar />", () => {
    it("renders message bar correctly", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<MessageBar messageBarType={MessageBarType.success} />);
        expect(wrapper.find('.ms-MessageBar--success').length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

This is the package.json file coming from `create-react-app` with few additions

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^6.110.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "3.1.5",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "23.0.0",
    "@types/react": "16.3.16",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.5",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
  }
}
```

**Error**
[image: Error from Jest]

`create-react-app` is not allowing me to specify ani options for `jest` in `package.json` without ejecting.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest

Comment: Did `npm install --save-dev babel-jest babel-core` and it didn't work

Comment: did you instantiate enzyme adapter?

Comment: also check your test files have `.jsx` extension

Answer (score -1):

After looking at the suggestions in the comments above, the following set worked for me:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^6.110.1",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
  }
}
```

In my test file `sample-tests.jsx`

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import { MessageBar, MessageBarType } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/MessageBar";

import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("<MessageBar />", () => {
    it("renders message bar correctly", () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<MessageBar messageBarType={MessageBarType.success} />);
        expect(wrapper.find('.ms-MessageBar--success').length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: None of this is necessary if using `create-react-app`. It supports jest with es modules out of the box. You should not add jest as a dependency in your own package.json at all; it's already done by react-scripts. Overriding that is not supported or recommended, and most likely broke the default behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932457/1057157

Comment: Your example works because you explicitly import the commonjs version of the package ("office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/MessageBar"). If you `import { MessageBar } from "office-ui-fabric-react"` then you likely get the same error.